# How can I allow a specific non-root user to run 'docker exec'?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, sudo, system-administration

How can I allow a non-root user to run 'docker exec' ?

For example, I would like to allow a user to execute the following command without him obtaining root permissions to the whole system:
`docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash`

This command would allow him to get inside his 'working environment' and do whatever he wants...
It would be great to be able to allow this command to him, without password requests

The operating system is Ubuntu server

Comment: If they can run that `docker exec` command, then they can also `docker run -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/shadow` and reset the host root user's password.  A Docker container is fundamentally a wrapper around a single process, and I wouldn't recommend doing extensive work in `docker exec` debugging shells.

Answer (score 1):

I probably found a solution to the problem.

First of all I ran:

`visudo`

then I inserted a new line:

```
studentxx ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash
```

then the non root user (studentxx) is able to execute the following command without any problems

```
sudo docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) something I found that seems to give a concise, step-by-step approach to what I'm deducting to be your problem. I will point out, though, that superuser is needed to prepare it.

~Roan